# Using unique_ptr as a member class and with list

Tags: c++, list, oop, c++11, unique-ptr

I recently made an application with 1 superclass and 2 subclasses. The main idea of it is storing information in 3 different list. My question is, can you only use 1 list for all 3 classes? Even though the 2 subclasses have some extra members. Someone told me that you could use unique_ptr as a member of the superclass and make only 1 list. I have read about it on the internet, but I can't quite get it. Any suggestions? Thank you for your time.

```
class Student {

     std::string Name;
     std::string Pinfo;
    std::map < std::string, float > Ngradelist;

public:

    std::string getName() {return Name;}

    std::string getPinfo() {return Pinfo;}

    virtual void InsertGradeList(std::string a, float b) {

        for(auto& it : Ngradelist)
            Ngradelist.insert(std::pair <std::string, float > (a,b));
    }

    Student( std::string n,  std::string p, std::map < std::string, float > Ng) :
        Name(std::move(n)), Pinfo(std::move(p)), Ngradelist(std::move(Ng)) {}

    virtual void Display() {

        std::cout << "Name: " << Name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Personal information: " << Pinfo << std::endl;
        std::cout << "NCourse:" << std::endl;
        for(auto& it : Ngradelist)
            std::cout << "   " << it.first << "   Grade: " << it.second <<  std::endl;
    }
};

class HWStudent : public Student {

    std::string FieldOfWork;
    std::map<std::string, float> HWgradelist;

public:

    void InsertGradeList(std::string a, float b) override{

        for (auto &it : HWgradelist)
            HWgradelist.insert(std::pair<std::string, float>(a, b));
    }

    HWStudent(std::string n, std::string p, std::map<std::string, float> Ng, std::string f,
            std::map<std::string, float> HWg) : Student(std::move(n), std::move(p), std::move(Ng)),
            FieldOfWork(std::move(f)), HWgradelist(std::move(HWg)) {}

    void Display() override {

        Student::Display();
        std::cout << "Field of Work: " << FieldOfWork << std::endl;
        std::cout << "HWCourse:" << std::endl;
        for(const auto& it : HWgradelist)
            std::cout << "   " << it.first << "   Grade: " << it.second <<  std::endl;
    }
};

class SWStudent : public Student {

    std::map<std::string, float> SWgradelist;
    std::list < std::string > Languages;

public:

    void InsertGradeList(std::string a, float b) override {

        for (const auto &it : SWgradelist)
            SWgradelist.insert(std::pair<std::string, float>(a, b));
    }

    SWStudent(std::string n, std::string p, std::map<std::string, float> Ng, std::list < std::string > l,
              std::map<std::string, float> SWg) : Student(std::move(n), std::move(p), std::move(Ng)),
              Languages(std::move(l)), SWgradelist(std::move(SWg)) {}

    void Display() override {

        Student::Display();
        std::cout << "SWCourse:" << std::endl;
        for(const auto& it : SWgradelist)
            std::cout << "   " << it.first << "   Grade: " << it.second <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << "SW Languages:" << std::endl;
        for(const auto& it : Languages)
            std::cout << "   " << it << std::endl;
    }
};

std::list < Student > listaStudenti;
std::list < HWStudent > HWlistaStudenti;
std::list < SWStudent > SWlistaStudenti;

    void InsertListaStudenti(unsigned short option) {
        unsigned short numbers;
        std::string name , pinfo, course, fieldofwork, hwcourse, swcourse;
        std::string language;
        float grade = 0, hwgrade, swgrade;
        std::list < std::string > languagelist;
        if(option == 1) {
            std::cout << "Insert name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "Insert personal information: ";
            std::cin >> pinfo;
            std::cout << "Insert course: ";
            std::cin >> course;
            std::cout << "Insert grade: ";
            std::cin >> grade;
            Student student(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}});
            listaStudenti.push_back(student);
        }
        if(option == 2) {
            std::cout << "Insert name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "Insert personal information: ";
            std::cin >> pinfo;
            std::cout << "Insert course: ";
            std::cin >> course;
            std::cout << "Insert grade: ";
            std::cin >> grade;
            std::cout << "Insert hwcourse: ";
            std::cin >> hwcourse;
            std::cout << "Insert hwgrade: ";
            std::cin >> hwgrade;
            std::cout << "Insert fieldofwork: ";
            std::cin >> fieldofwork;
            HWStudent hwstudent(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}}, fieldofwork,{{hwcourse, hwgrade}});
            HWlistaStudenti.push_back(hwstudent);
        }
        if(option == 3) {
            std::cout << "Insert name: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << "Insert personal information: ";
            std::cin >> pinfo;
            std::cout << "Insert course: ";
            std::cin >> course;
            std::cout << "Insert grade: ";
            std::cin >> grade;
            std::cout << "Insert swcourse: ";
            std::cin >> swcourse;
            std::cout << "Insert swgrade: ";
            std::cin >> swgrade;
            std::cout << "How many  languages: ";
            std::cin >> numbers;
            for(auto it = 0;it < numbers; ++it) {
                std::cout << "Insert language: ";
                std::cin >> language;
            languagelist.push_back(language);
            }
            SWStudent swstudent(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}},languagelist,{{swcourse, swgrade}});
            SWlistaStudenti.push_back(swstudent);
        }
    }

int main() {

    unsigned short option = 10;
    while(option != 0) {
        std::cout << "1.Add student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2.Add HW student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3.Add SW student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4.Display Student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5.Display HW Student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6.Display SW Student." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "0 is for exit." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Option is : ";
        std::cin >> option;
        switch  (option) {
            case 0 : {
                std::cout <<" You chose to leave.";
                exit;
                break;
            }
            case 1 : {
               InsertListaStudenti(option);
                break;
            }
            case 2 : {
                InsertListaStudenti(option);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                InsertListaStudenti(option);
                break;
            }

            case 4: {

                for(auto &it : listaStudenti)
                    it.Display();
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                for(auto &it : HWlistaStudenti)
                    it.Display();
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                for(auto &it : SWlistaStudenti)
                    it.Display();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Student>> students;
```

instead of

```
std::list<Student> listaStudenti;
std::list<HWStudent> HWlistaStudenti;
std::list<SWStudent> SWlistaStudenti;
```

- with insertion similar to

  ```
  Student student(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}});
  students.push_back(std::make_unique<Student>(std::move(student)));
  // or std::make_unique<Student>(name, pinfo, std::map<std::string, float>{{course, grade}})

  HWStudent hwstudent(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}}, fieldofwork, {{hwcourse, hwgrade}});
  students.push_back(std::make_unique<HWStudent>(std::move(hwstudent));
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  Student student(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}});
  listaStudenti.push_back(student);

  HWStudent hwstudent(name, pinfo, {{course, grade}}, fieldofwork,{{hwcourse, hwgrade}});
  HWlistaStudenti.push_back(hwstudent);
  ```
- Issue would be with your "filtering":

  ```
  for (auto& student : SWlistaStudenti) {
      student.Display();
  }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  for (auto& studentPtr : SWlistaStudenti) {
      if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<SWStudent*>(studentPtr.get())) ptr->Display();
  }
  ```

  but (to show only regular students (not HW/SW))

  ```
  for(auto& student : listaStudenti) { student.Display(); }
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  for (auto& studentPtr : students) {
      if (!dynamic_cast<SWStudent*>(studentPtr.get())
          && !dynamic_cast<HWStudent*>(studentPtr.get())) {
          studentPtr->Display();
      }
  }
  ```
- One list allows to treats them equality BTW:

  To display all students:

  ```
  for (auto& studentPtr : students) { studentPtr->Display(); }
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  for (auto& student : listaStudenti) { student.Display(); }
  for (auto& student : HWlistaStudenti) { student.Display(); }
  for (auto& student : SWlistaStudenti) { student.Display(); }
  ```

Comment: `std::make_unique` is C++14, but can be implemented in C++11.

Comment: From your shown needs, 3 containers seems betters though IMO.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have made the changes and it works. How can I only display HW students or only SW students ? I have changed your if statement( the one with dynamic cast in it) so that it applies for HW or SW students but when I try to display that, nothing pops on the console. Displaying all students or just normal students work. ( Im just trying to learn more of c++ and how it works, with this example I started from simple constructor, to what it is now, while i develop this app further more, I learn more of c++ and I find it easier on examples, than just reading theory)

Comment: Sorry man, I was blind. I saw that it was the old list( used only for SWStudents) and didn't pay attention to it. Again thank you and have a wonderful day.